# Правильно ли стоят запятые в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, определения

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в данном предложении?

*Подсудимый совершил преступление, редкое по смелости, ловкости и богатству фантазии.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятые стоят правильно.

*Подсудимый совершил преступление, **редкое по смелости, ловкости и богатству фантазии.***

Первая запятая отделяет определительный оборот от определяемого слова, а вторая – однородные члены внутри него.

> 1. Обособляются (отделяются запятой, а в середине предложения выделяются с двух сторон запятыми) распространенные определения, выраженные причастием или прилагательным с зависящими от него словами (так называемые определительные обороты), стоящие **после** существительного или субстантивированного слова: <...> *Нас окружал со всех сторон сплошной вековой бор, **равный по величине доброму княжеству*** (Купр.).

Источник: [*Согласованные определения*](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108) (справочник Розенталя).